# Not able to get data from fire base database

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am working on fire base and push data to server successfully and able to save data in database using model class. My structure of database looks like.

[image]

***Retrieve Data* :**

```
    FirebaseDatabase firebaseDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    DatabaseReference mref = firebaseDatabase.getReference();
    mref.orderByChild("jetbro").addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            for (DataSnapshot child : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                  Log.d("User val", child.getValue(UserModel.class).getName());// Null Pointer
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
```

**Updated Code:**

```
    FirebaseDatabase firebaseDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    DatabaseReference mref = firebaseDatabase.getReference();

    mref.orderByChild("jetbro").addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
                Log.d("User val", dataSnapshot.getValue(UserModel.class).getName());
        }

        @Override
        public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
```

But it gives me null pointer exception. Can any one have before?

Advance help would be appreciated !

Comment: could u also show your Model class, if possible

Comment: hey, can you please upload a new pic of your database structure in firebase with all your nodes expanded, so that i can update my answer accordingly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I have solved issue :

```
 FirebaseDatabase firebaseDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    DatabaseReference mref = firebaseDatabase.getReference();
    mref.child("jetbro").addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
            ChatModel chatModel = dataSnapshot.getValue(ChatModel.class);
            UserModel usermodel = chatModel.getUserModel();
        }

        @Override
        public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all if u want to get child from inside `random key` you should use `addChildEventValueListerner` instead of `addListenerForSingleValueEvent` because it gives the direct value i.e `random key` as child, whereas `addChildEventValueListerner` gives u child of the `jetbro` node **one by one**.

and if u think that i just want to use it for single time `addChildEventValueListerner` only gives data when something **added, changed, removed** which is quiet useful many times

```
 mRef.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
            Log.d("User val",datasnapshot);
        }

        @Override
        public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
```

Comment: Can you please show some code? After using _addChildEventListener_ it gives me same result

Comment: u can check it now

Comment: I think the error is because u have used  object (`userModel`) with strings (`message,timestamp`)

Answer (score 0):

```
class DataModel{
  String message,timeStamp;
  DataModel(String message, String timeStamp){
     this.message = message;
     this.timeStamp = timeStamp;
  }

  DataModel(){
  }
}
```

Make a Data Model like above (**make sure your key names in firebase database and variables in your Data Model have the same name**)

Use a ChildEventListener to retrieve the data with your Reference

```
mRef.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
            DataModel data = dataSnapshot.getValue(DataModel.class);

            //here you can now access your message and timestamp data
            data.message 
            data.timeStamp
        }

        @Override
        public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
```

I don't know whats inside your `userModel` Node in `Firebase`, but you would have to make a new Class as `DataModel` for the contents in `UserModel` itself. 
then a `Arraylist` named `userModel` in your `DataModel` class.

Comment: if jetbro is not your root, you should use  `mref.child("jetbro").addChildEventListener()` if its your root, use `mref.addChildEventListener()` directly

Comment: Please check my database structure

Comment: according to your database structure jetbro seems to be the root, so you should use mref.addChildEventListener() directly

Comment: I used the same still problem occurs